# QT: How do I convert QBitArray to QString?

Tags: c++, arrays, qstring

I want to convert a QBitArray into QString to display its values on `QTextEdit`, but I couldn't.

Here is how I convert it:

```
String MainWindow::arrToStr(QBitArray arr)
{
    QString arrStr = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.size(); i++)
    {
        arrStr += arr.at(i);
    }
    return arrStr;
}
```

.. I get the following QString:

> "\001\000\000\000\000\001\000\001\001\000\001\000\001\000\000\000\001\001\001\000\001\001\001\001\001\000\000\001\000\000\001"

However, when I dispaly it on `QPlainTextEdit` I see happy faces, yes I see lot of those `:-)` (as an imoji), I'm not kidding.

If I try to display it on `QTextEdit`, nothing is shown.

would someone please explain to me what is happening ?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse : Sorry, still not working. i convert the QBitArray and followed the answer still I am getting samples and weired signs

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse : Yes, at least it is generating the expected values. When I use `qDebug()` I see the output as `true` and `false` in the "Application Output". And when I debug the value during runtime, I see the above binray values (i.e.: 0101010...). So, I guess it is working fine. But, I cannot show its value on `QTextEdit` as QString !!

Comment: Seems working as expected. Those happy faces are characters with ASCII code of 1; characters with ASCII code of 0 don't have a visible representation. You probably want something like `arrStr += arr.at(i) ? '1' : '0';`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : Yes, execatly. it worked, how come I didn't thought of that ;-) . Many Thanks :-D